# Drupal 8: You have requested a non-existent service "router.route_provider.old"

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am creating two custom content type with reference to these pages:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2629550

https://www.drupal.org/node/2693979

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   "You have requested a non-existent service
>   "router.route_provider.old". Did you mean one of these:
>   "router.route_provider", "router.route_preloader"?" at
>   ...\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php
>   line 157

Could anyone please help me, why this is happening and how to fix it ?

I am using Drupal 8.1.8 version.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code around line 52 of `DiscoveryTrait.php`?

Comment: Here is the code around 52:

protected function doGetDefinition(array $definitions, $plugin_id, $exception_on_invalid) {
    // Avoid using a ternary that would create a copy of the array.
    if (isset($definitions[$plugin_id])) {
      return $definitions[$plugin_id];
    }
    elseif (!$exception_on_invalid) {
      return NULL;
    }

    throw new PluginNotFoundException($plugin_id, sprintf('The "%s" plugin does not exist.', $plugin_id));
}

Comment: That is very hard to read and people may not see that here in the comments.  Please edit your question to include that.  I know nothing about Drupal, just trying to help you get your question answered.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Plugin%21Discovery%21DiscoveryTrait.php/trait/DiscoveryTrait/8.2.x

see function name : doGetDefinition() where it throws the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked in core.services.yml file, there is no route declared as "router.route_provider.old"

I have created a router names as "router.route_provider.old" by copying "router.route_provider" in the core.services.yml file, which solves my problem.

i think Drupal uses "router.route_provider.old" router as a temporary to copy "router.route_provider" router info. But as this router name is not exists, its throwing exception.

I don't know if this is a bug or there is better way to fix it.

**Update:**
A patch is provided here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2788087